# An angle bisector of length $4$ units, creates a $6$ unit line segment on the base of the triangle. What are possible integer values of its side?

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

> What is the sum of the possible integer values of $x$

**My Solution**

I know that $\angle DAC \lt 90^o$ because it is an angle bisector, therefore:

$$4^2+x^2 \lt 6^2 \quad \quad  6-4 \lt x \lt 6+4$$

Combining these two I get:
$$2 \lt x \lt 5 \quad x\in Z$$

But this is wrong according to the answer key. How can I solve this problem?

**Edit:** Inequality should have been $4^2+x^2 \gt 6^2$, though still I'm getting a wrong answer (The sum should be $24$):

$$4 \lt x \lt 10 \quad (\sum x =35)\quad  x \in Z$$

Comment: It should be $4^2+x^2\gt6^2$ as the cosine rule gives $6^2=x^2+4^2-2(x)(4)\cos{(\lt90^\circ)}$

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yes, I know, hence I've $x\lt 10$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $x < 10.$ It is not hard to construct a valid figure in which $x = 9$ and all of the given conditions hold.
So the question is what the minimum value of $x$ is.

Note that if $\angle ADC$ is less than a right angle, as it certainly would be if 
$x < \sqrt{6^2 + 4^2} = \sqrt{52},$
then $\angle ADB$ is greater than a right angle and
$\lvert AB\rvert > \lvert BD\rvert.$
But since $AD$ bisects $\angle BAC,$
we have $\frac x6 = \frac{\lvert AB\rvert}{\lvert BD\rvert} > 1.$
Therefore $x > 6.$

Another way to find the same constraint is that in order for the sides $AB$ and $BC$ to intersect as shown in the figure, we require that $\angle ADC > \angle CAD,$
which implies that $x > 6.$

For good measure you can confirm that the figure can be constructed if $x=7,$
$x=8,$ or $x=9.$  But you will not find any stricter constraints than $6 < x < 10.$

So the sum of possible values of $x$ is $7+8+9=24.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't understand why $x < \sqrt{6^2 + 4^2} = \sqrt{52}$? We also might have had $\angle ADC$ to be less than a right angle, and then got $\sum x = 5 + 6 + 7 = 18$

Comment: The significance of the condition $x<\sqrt{52}$ is merely that it is satisfied by all three of the values $x=5,$ $x=6,$ and $x=7,$ and that it _implies_ that $\angle ADC$ is less than a right angle. I then pursue this implication further to show that $x > 6.$ I never said that $x<\sqrt{52}$ is a necessary condition for constructing the figure as shown; in fact it is violated for $x=8$ and $x=9,$ which are both values of $x$ for which such a figure exists.

Comment: If you like, you can skip the paragraph in which I considered the condition $x<\sqrt{52}$ and read the next paragraph instead, which shows (in a different way) that $x > 6.$

Comment: I got it. Many thanks

Comment: And thanks for alerting me that I had written the wrong angle name in the answer!

Answer (score 2):

We are missing the forest for the trees.  The true bound has nothing to do with the Pythagorean Theorem or the Law of Cosines.

In $\triangle ABD$, the exterior angle ADC must have a greater measure than the opposing interior angle DAB.  By the bisection requirement, $\angle DAB$ is in turn congruent to $\angle CAD$.

So, in $\triangle ADC$, $\angle ADC$ must be larger than $\angle CAD$, forcing the opposite sides to have the same ordering:  $CA=x$ must be greater than $DC=6$.